# returning a vector in get/set method

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am trying to use a get/set method in c++ for a vector. I keep getting an error throwing an instance of std::out_of_range which occurs when i try to cout the index value of **ego_points.at(1)** in my main code. I am providing my header file and my main code below but I'll try to explain here:

I have a class called **Points** with a public function called **ScanCallback** that builds the vector **scannedData** and uses the **set** function to set the private vector **transmittedData** equal to the **scannedData**. In my main code, I have an object called **p1** of the **Points** class and I am trying to set a vector called **ego_points** equal to the **transmittedData** of object **p1**. I am able to build the vector ego_points by using the getVector() function but cannot access it's data. Anyone know why not?

Header File:

```
#pragma once
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "motor_driver/Motor_speeds.h"
#include "motor_driver/cartesian.h"
#include <vector>

#ifndef MOTOR_DRIVER_H
#define MOTOR_DRIVER_H

using namespace std;
using namespace motor_driver;

class Points {
        public:
                vector<float> scannedData;
                int i;
                int size;
                int size1;
                int size2;

                Points() : scannedData(0) {}            //Must match the class name. This is the constructor.

                void set(vector<float> transmittingData){
                        transmittedData = transmittingData;
                }

                void ScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan) {
                                scannedData.clear();
                                size = scan->ranges.size();
                                scannedData.resize(size);
                                for(i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1){
                                        scannedData.at(i) = scan->ranges[i];
                                }
                                set(scannedData);
                }

                int getSize(){
                        return size;
                }

                vector<float> getVector(){
                        return transmittedData;
                }

        private:
                vector<float> transmittedData;
};
#endif
```

Main Code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "motor_driver/Motor_speeds.h"
#include "motor_driver/cartesian.h"
#include <motor_driver.h>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
using namespace motor_driver;
Points p1;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "motor_driver_node");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        ros::Subscriber sub;
        ros::Rate r(1);
        int ss;
        int newsize;
        int index;
        vector<float> ego_points;
        while (ros::ok()) {
                sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan",10, &Points::ScanCallback, &p1);
                newsize = p1.getSize();
                ego_points.clear();
                ego_points.resize(newsize);
                ego_points = p1.getVector();
                cout << ego_points.at(1) << endl;
                r.sleep();
                ros::spinOnce();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

My error:

```
:~/Desktop/Naes_Thesis$ rosrun motor_driver motor_driver_node 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you about the size of the vector contained in `p1`?

Answer (score 0):

does the vector have at least two elements? If you want to access the first element you should use:

```
cout << ego_points.at(0) << endl;
```

Also the size method is probably incorrect. It should be something like this:

```
int getSize() const {
    return transmittedData.size();
}
```

Otherwise the size may contain a different value than the actual vector size

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1) yes the vector is more than one element (it usually has 360 elements), I wasn't trying to get the first element by using 1, I just threw a number in there. 2)  I modified to the getSize function as you suggested. I am still getting the error though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. The issue was that the size of the vector is 0 until the vector is built. So I added a if (vector =0) then (do nothing) portion to the code and it fixed it. Thank you Noel-lopes and 1201ProgramAlarm for your contribution.